# data type error when assigning filepath value to variable ssis

Tags: c#, ssis, type-conversion

I am trying to assign a specific value to a variable which is of a file path but i a, getting an error on data types. See the following image. It shows the error and the expression i am using to assign the value to the variable

[Image for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75tpw.png)

Comment: Move the CAST as STR statement so that it is immediately in front of @errorCount. Something like `RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,12,1252)(@[user::_Errorcount],2)`

Comment: yup that worked. cheers